# Combine list element by column name to make a dataframe

Tags: r, list

I have a example of list like follow

```
lst<-list(setNames(c(1,10,50,60,70,80),c("id","id1","math","phy","che","bio")),setNames(c(2,20,45),c("id","id1","phy")),setNames(c(3,30,75),c("id","id1","bio")))
```

My expected outcome :

```
df<-rbind(c(1,10,50,60,70,80),c(2,20,NA,45,NA,NA),c(3,30,NA,NA,NA,75))
colnames(df)<-c("id","id1","math","phy","che","bio")
df
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated . 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `rbindlist` from the devel version of 'data.table' i.e. v1.9.5.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) #v1.9.5+
rbindlist(lapply(lst, as.data.frame.list), fill=TRUE)
#    id id1 math phy che bio
#1:  1  10   50  60  70  80
#2:  2  20   NA  45  NA  NA
#3:  3  30   NA  NA  NA  75
```

Comment: Thanks !! Working instantly .

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
nms = unique(unlist(lapply(lst, names)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, "[", nms))
#     id id1 math phy che bio
#[1,]  1  10   50  60  70  80
#[2,]  2  20   NA  45  NA  NA
#[3,]  3  30   NA  NA  NA  75
```

Answer (score -1):

Another ways of doing it :

Base R solution for the above problem would be

```
dataFrame <- do.call(rbind,List)
```

OR dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
dataFrame <- rbind_all(List)
```

Comment: dataFrame <- do.call(rbind,List) ... dont work with unequal list length